# SQL use @variable with the IN operator to INSERT INTO a table

Tags: sql, sybase

The following code works.  However, I am trying to preform this same function multiple times throughout an SQL.  Therefore, I would like to declare a variable so the user only has to update that with the logon names at the beginning of the SQL.

```
INSERT user_role (logon, role_name)
SELECT logon, 'QUERY' AS 'role_name' 
FROM user_table 
WHERE logon NOT IN ( 'bill', 'tim', 'dave'  )
```

When I add the variable @Names, the IN operator doesn't return the correct results.  It is basically ignores the variable and inserts all users into the table.  If I change "( @Names )" to just "@Names" in the WHERE statement I get an incorrect syntax error near keyword @Names.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @Names = " 'bill', 'tim', 'dave' "

INSERT user_role (logon, role_name)
SELECT logon, 'QUERY' AS 'role_name' 
FROM user_table 
WHERE logon NOT IN ( @Names )
```

I did come across the EXEC function, but it doesn't appear to work in conjunction with the INSERT function.  I get an incorrect syntax error near keyword EXEC.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @Names = " 'bill', 'tim', 'dave' "

INSERT user_role (logon, role_name)
EXEC("SELECT logon, 'QUERY' AS 'role_name' 
FROM user_table
WHERE logon NOT IN ("+@Names+")")
```

I even tried changing up the sequence of where the INSERT statement was and this didn't work either. I get an incorrect syntax error near keyword FROM.

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @Names = " 'bill', 'tim', 'dave' "

EXEC("SELECT logon, 'QUERY' AS 'role_name' 
INSERT user_role (logon, role_name)
FROM user_table 
WHERE logon NOT IN ("+@Names+")")
```

I am trying to replicate this SQL to use at multiple sites and minimize the amount of user interaction to make it work.  Hopefully there is a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last one code you you have to change the `INSERT` and `SELECT` order:

```
DECLARE @Names VARCHAR(100)
SELECT @Names = " 'bill', 'tim', 'dave' "

EXEC("INSERT user_role (logon, role_name)
SELECT logon, 'QUERY' AS 'role_name' 
FROM user_table 
WHERE logon NOT IN ("+@Names+")")
```

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, double quotes are field name identifiers, like square brackets are.  You must use single quotes for string literals.

Try this:

```
SELECT @Names = ' ''bill'', ''tim'', ''dave'' '
```